# openCV SURF error

Tags: c++, opencv

**i'm using opencv 2.44 , viusal studio c++ 2010**
when i compliel i get this error

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SURF::SURF(void)" (??0SURF@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\user\Desktop\proiect\prj\prj\sh1.obj   prj

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
using namespace cv;
void main(){
char i; 
Mat image,img,ref;
ref=imread("hh.jpg");
// create window to show image 
namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("costel", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("fanel", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
Mat ig,ib,ibb;
Mat bkg;
Mat prev;
Mat stor;
cvtColor(ref, ref, CV_BGR2GRAY);
FastFeatureDetector detector(15);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1;
detector.detect(ref, keypoints1);
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1;
extractor.compute(ref, keypoints1, descriptors1);

....
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems for me a problem in setting the project properties.
properties->linker->input->additional dependencies in VS. May be you double check if you added opencv_features2d244.lib and opencv_nonfree244.lib

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy all the DLL you need to use to the DEBUG folder or where your exe sits.
2. Check all the source path and header path

Good luck. You are likely on a missing DLL myth, find opencv_nonfree244.dll , opencv_features2d244.dll and all other dll in your cv installation folder and copy them to the   folder should fix it.